# Django view timeout handler

Tags: django, slack

I'm writing a [Slack](https://slack.com/) slash Command handler and I noticed that my responses don't get forwarded if they don't fit in the timeout of about five seconds.

How could I wrap my Django view with a function that would detect if we're about to hit the timeout and if that's the case, terminate the connection with a specific response?